# Error: 'StudentScore' is a type, which is not valid in the given context

Tags: c#, linq

Join the two collections and calculate the total score of each student by subject.

```
public class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class StudentScore
    {
        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string Subject { get; set; }
        public int Points { get; set; }
    }
public class StudentScoress
    {

        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var totalscore = from s in Student
                             join ss in StudentScore
                             on s.Id equals ss.StudentId
                             group ss by ss.Subject into sss
                             select new { sss.Name, sss.Subject, sss.Points };

            foreach (var ts in totalscore)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}" + " " + "{1}" + " " + "{2}", ts.Name, ts.Subject, ts.Points);
            }
        }

        IEnumerable<Student> student = new List<Student>()
        {
            new Student() {Id=1,Name="Sam",Age=16},
            new Student() {Id=2,Name="Rick",Age=16},
            new Student() {Id=3,Name="Warner",Age=17},
        };

        IEnumerable<StudentScore> studentScores = new List<StudentScore>()
        {
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 1, Subject = "Maths", Points = 54},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 1, Subject = "Maths", Points = 32},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 1, Subject = "English", Points = 55},      
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 1, Subject = "English", Points = 54},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 1, Subject = "Biology", Points = 32},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 1, Subject = "Biology", Points = 27},          

            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 2, Subject = "Maths", Points = 44},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 2, Subject = "Maths", Points = 37},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 2, Subject = "English", Points = 59},  
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 2, Subject = "English", Points = 64},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 2, Subject = "Biology", Points = 42},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 2, Subject = "Biology", Points = 67},          

            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 3, Subject = "Maths", Points = 53},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 3, Subject = "Maths", Points = 72},            
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 3, Subject = "English", Points = 54},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 3, Subject = "English", Points = 59},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 3, Subject = "Biology", Points = 87},
            new StudentScore() { StudentId = 3, Subject = "Biology", Points = 34}
        };
    }
```

I'm getting error in LINQ query that 'StudentScore' is a type, which is not valid in the given context.

What I'm missing here. Anyone help me out.

Comment: It must be `from s in student join ss in studentScores` - you must reference your variables, not the classes in the query.

Comment: @germi Thanks..it gives a clarity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Demo on dotnet fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sVhf0I)

1. You should replace `Student` model by `student` list.
2. You should replace `StudentScore` model by `studentScores` list.
3. You need to group by 2 fields `new {s.Name, ss.Subject}` to be able to get in selecting result.
4. Use ***Aggregate Operators*** like `Sum` function to get `TotalScore` or [`Average`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/query-expression-syntax-examples-aggregate-operators#average) or [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/query-expression-syntax-examples-aggregate-operators#count), [`Max`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/query-expression-syntax-examples-aggregate-operators#max), [`Min`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/query-expression-syntax-examples-aggregate-operators#min) etc.

```
        var totalscore = from s in student
            join ss in studentScores on s.Id equals ss.StudentId
            group ss by new {s.Name, ss.Subject} into sss
            select new { sss.Key.Name, sss.Key.Subject, TotalScore = sss.Sum(p => p.Points)  };

        foreach (var ts in totalscore)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}" + " " + "{1}" + " " + "{2}", ts.Name, ts.Subject, ts.TotalScore);
        }
```

**Output**

```
Sam Maths 86
Sam English 109
Sam Biology 59
Rick Maths 81
Rick English 123
Rick Biology 109
Warner Maths 125
Warner English 113
Warner Biology 121
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Phong Would like to ask some questions for my clarification.

Comment: 1.How to call student and studentScore variables if I place the IEnumerables outside main method. 2. Why should I add Name field in the group by because I want to group by based on Subject. 3. How to display the output without repeating Names in the output like  Name: Sam, Total score by subject: {“Maths”:86,”English”:109,”Biology”:59}

Comment: 1. Why do you want to place it outside the method? You can create other methods like `GetListOfStudents`, etc. After that, you can call the method.

Comment: In the second question, We should keep the question simple as much as possible (Help the reader in the future). So you can create another question? (With the corresponding the result). Send me the question link. I'm willing to help you.

Comment: Sure @phong.. i'll follow your suggestion in forthcoming posts.

Comment: 2. Why should I add Name field in the group by because I want to group by based on Subject.

Comment: 3. How to display the output without repeating Names in the output like Name: Sam, Total score by subject: {“Maths”:86,”English”:109,”Biology”:59}

Comment: 4.TotalScore = sss.Sum(p=> p.Points) Why the fields in the StudentScore class alone pops up for the intellisense "p. " in the aggregation, Why not fields of Student class.

Comment: You should create a new question 3, because it's quite complex.

Comment: Question 4: Because `group ss` of `studentScores ` so you might not able to access properties of `Student ` class. There is one way you can achieve it by selecting flat items combined with both of them. After that, you can group by then access both of them.

Comment: @Krish Have you created other questions? Send me question links When you're done.